# Testing if an integer is an uppercase ASCII letter using bit manipulation

Tags: c

For an assignment, I'm trying to make some code in C that uses only bit manipulation to test if an integer is an ASCII uppercase letter. The letter will be given by its ASCII code in integer form, meaning `0x41 <= ourint <= 0x5A`. After doing some research I learned that the difference between a lower case and an upper case letter was the sixth digit of the binary version of the word. Uppercase had a `1` and lower had a `0`.

I am almost have it, but my code won't work.

What I have so far is

```
!(((x>>6)<<31) & 0)
```

What it does is shifts the code to the right 6 to get the sixth digit as the first number, then shifts right 31 to get it to be either all 0's or 1 followed by 31 0's. I have to make it so that if it is uppercase it returns 1, so I use the exclamation point to that.

**EDIT:** my new code is

```
!((~(((x & 32)>>5))<<31))>>31)
```

but now I am stuck on the test problem of `0x7fffffff`

Comment: You invoke possible undefined and implementation defined behaviour in the bit-shifts. And `int` does not necessarily have 32 bits.

Comment: @olaf I am to assume that the integers in this problem have 32 bits. I also know that all left shifts are logical, meaning they will leave behind 0's

Comment: Two words: **bit mask**

Comment: If you just use `'A' <= x && x <= 'Z'`, the compiler will do the magic for you.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: True, but the task is to do it by bit manipulation.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp I am not allowed to use If,then,else or anything other than basic bit-manipulation

Comment: @Beta: If we narrowly interpret every question here, the site would be poor indeed.

Comment: Why don't you just do `x & 0x20`?

Comment: @ FUZxxl I tried that too and I keep getting an error when testing 0x80000000

Comment: While I also presume you use 32 bit `int` with 2's complement encoding, relying on that is bad style. About the shifts: Provide a [mcve]! You likely assume wrong! And it is both shifts which are problematic. Read the standard.

Comment: @user3483844 how is `0x80000000 ` an ASCII encoded letter?

Comment: Use `ctypes.h` `isupper()`. That likely does use bit-ops. And for just testing you don't have to manipulate a bit. That code is wrong (not only for the IDB/UB) and bad style anyway.

Comment: @user3483844 It isn't, but it's just testing to see if an interger falls between the range of 0x41 and 0x5A using bit manipulation

Comment: You can easily check if it really does. Write a simple program around it. Short: an [mcve]!

Comment: @olaf That doens't help because that's not the issue at hand. I can write a regular code checking that, but not in bit manipulation

Comment: *"Uppercase had a 1 and lower had a 0."* -- it the other way around.

Comment: Are you going for a master in unmaintainable code ?

Comment: also, @user3483844: you need to get in the habit of accepting answers when they solve your problems.  You've asked 12 separate questions and not accepted any of the answers people have provided.

Comment: `return (c & 0b100000) == 0;` returns true if c is an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can test if an ASCII letter `c` is upper case by checking its `0x20` bit, it must be `0` for uppercase and `1` for lowercase:

```
if (!(c & 0x20))
    printf("ASCII letter %c is uppercase\n", c);
```

but be aware that this test does not work if you don't already know that `c` is a letter.  It would erroneously match `'@'` and `'['`, `'\\'`, `']'`, `'^'` and `'_'`, and the whole range of characters with the high bit set from 192 to 223, which are not part of ASCII but are valid `unsigned char` values.

If you want a single test to verify if `c` is an uppercase ASCII letter, try:

```
if ((unsigned)(c - 'A') <= (unsigned)('Z' - 'A'))
     printf("%c is an uppercase ASCII letter\n", c);
```

**EDIT:** it is unclear what you mean by *I am not allowed to use if statements, or any kind of type casting operations. I must test to see if the number is between the two numbers, including numbers far outside the range of the ASCII code, and return 1 if it is or else 0*.

- If you know `c` is a letter, both `!(c & 0x20)` and `(((c >> 5) & 1) ^ 1)` will have value `1` if `c` is uppercase and `0` if not.
- If `c` can be any integer value, just write the regular comparison `(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')` and the compiler will produce better code than you would by attempting hazardous bit-twiddling tricks.

**EDIT again**:

Since `c` can be any integer value and you are only allowed bit manipulations, here is another solution: `!((c >> 5) ^ 2) & (0x07fffffeU >> (c & 31))`.  Below is a program to test this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int uppertest(int c) {
    return !((c >> 5) ^ 2) & (0x07fffffeU >> (c & 31));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        int c = strtol(argv[i], NULL, 0);
        printf("uppertest(%d) -> %d\n", c, uppertest(c));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am not allowed to use if statements, or any kind of type casting operations. I must test to see if the number is between the two numbers, including numbers far outside the range of the ASCII code, and return 1 if it is or else 0.

Comment: The first code fragment is wrong. All letters have bit 6 set. And both `printf()` miss the value to print.

Comment: @axiac: I indeed got carried away... I updated the post with correct code (I hope).

Comment: @user3483844: the `if` statement is just for illustrative purposes, just use the expression between the parentheses.  If this some kind of assignment where bitwise operations are required, look at my update,

Comment: In considering codepoints 192 to 223, you've left ASCII. So the questions would be which character set and encoding is it; and, what the the upper letters in that character set? @user3483844, that's why C has libraries for this sort of thing.

Comment: @TomBlodget: the OP's question is unclear: can `x` have any integer value or not? Regarding the definition os *uppercase letter*, I don't think there is an ambiguity, only ASCII uppercase letters `A` though `Z` are targeted.

Comment: @TomBlodget Yes, my value going in is an Integer. To simplify the problem I need to test if it is between 0x41 and 0x5A (Uppercase A and Z in ASCII). I can only use basic bit manipulation and I will be getting a wide range of values both in and outside the ASCII range.

Comment: @user3483844: OK, so `x` can be any integer value. See updated code.

Comment: @chqrlie indeed, I downvoted its first version. It looks better now.

Comment: As a long time sustaining engineer, I'd prefer the expression as `(0x07fffffeU >> (c&0x1F)) & !(( c ^ 'A')>> 5)`.  This highlights the operator binding order (most don't notice that ! binds before &) and the high bit pattern match is more apparent.  Both are nods to human frailty...great solution.

Comment: @Speed8ump: interesting alternative... one can use any uppercase ASCII letter, but the source character must be ASCII. `0x07fffffeU` could also be constructed more explicitly as `~(~0u << ('Z'&0x1F)) << ('A'&0x1F)`.

Answer (score 1):

> ...  to see if a letter is uppercase

Simplification:
Let us assume ranges [A-Z] and [a-z] `char` differ by the same value which is a power of 2.  So `'B'-'b'`  equals `'X'-'x'`, etc.

```
#define CASE_MASK ('A' ^ 'a')

// Is letter uppercase?
int is_letter_upper(int ch) {
   return (ch & CASE_MASK) == ('A' & CASE_MASK);
}

// Is letter lowercase?
int is_letter_lower(int ch) {
   return (ch & CASE_MASK) == ('a' & CASE_MASK);
}
```

This works for [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) and [EBCIDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)

A more "bit manipulation" answer

```
int is_letter_upperBM(int ch) {
   return !((ch & CASE_MASK) ^ ('A' & CASE_MASK));
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am taking in an integer value, not a char. And I must use bit manipulation

Comment: @user3483844 `char` is an integer value as are 'A' and 'a'. And, are you sure you're not interpreting [bit manipulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation) too strictly?

Comment: @user3483844 `is_letter_upperBM()` only uses `!&^` and no compare.

Comment: @chux: OP clarified he wants a generalized `isupper()` expression that works for any `int` value and uses only bit manipulations. Technically, `!` is not a bitwise operator, it is a logical operator.

Comment: @chqrlie Hmmm, OP has not changed the post yet to reflect `generalized isupper()` but states " to see if a letter is uppercase".  Agree about `!`, although other applications like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation#Example_of_bit_manipulation) use `!` as a bit manipulator.  OP's moving/fuzzy target reduces this post's value.

Comment: @chux: my bad, the question was inconsistent and I had misinterpreted it when I edited it to specify *to see if a letter is uppercase*.  Various comments by the OP made it clear `x` can be any `int` value.

Comment: @chqrlie OP also said "ASCII code" and "Uppercase had a 1 and lower had a 0", so the clarity/veracity of OP's post and comments are all questionable. + 1 for your efforts to untangle this..

Answer (score 0):

Since OP is stuck on case `0x7fffffff`, exclude it by extending the otherwise working solution.

```
!((~(((x & 32)>>5))<<31))>>31) & !(x ^ 0x7fffffff)
```

Pedantically, just code as below and let the compiler simplify.

```
isupper = (!(x ^ 'A')) | (!(x ^ 'B')) | (!(x ^ 'C')) ... (!(x ^ 'Z'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use *unsigned* integer division, if that's allowed:

```
!((x-0x41)/26)
```

But that's probably not in the spirit of the original question.  Consider what happens when you subtract 0x3B from any upper case letter:

```
A: 0x41 - 0x3B = 0x06
Z: 0x5A - 0x3B = 0x1F
```

The interesting feature here is that any value initially larger than 0x5A will have one of the high bits set (~0x1F).  You can perform the same shifting for moving 'A' down to zero, so anything initially less than 'A' would have the high bits set.  In the end a solution requires only subtractions, an or, and some bit-wise ands:

```
!(((x-0x3B) & ~(0x1F)) || ((x-0x41) & ~(0x1F)))
```

I believe that does what you want.  Given the nature of conditional (short circuit) evaluation in C, this has an implicit conditional embedded in it though.  If you want to remove that, minimize the computation, and maximize the obscurity you could do this:

```
!(((x-0x3B) | (x-0x41)) & ~(0x1F))
```

or my new personal favorite:

```
!((('Z'-x) | (x-'A')) & ~(0x1F))
```

Comment: I like the poker eyes operator too:  `!(('Z' -x|x- 'A') & ~0x1F)`