# How to return 1 if the ASCII is uppercase

Tags: c

I have to return 1 if x is in between 0x41 and 0x5a (ascii for 'A' to 'Z'). Only bitwise operators are allowed (`~`, `&`, `^`, `|`, `<<`, `>>`), plus `!` and `+`. Library functions like `isupper` are not.

I'd appreciate any tips or help because I understand which ranges work, but I don't know how to manipulate it to return 1 with the given operators.

Comment: @JohnKugelman no they are not, which is why this is driving me crazy

Comment: @JohnKugelman ! and + are allowed, but - is not

Comment: How about negative numbers?

Comment: @PhatWrat no they are not

Comment: I think someone in the same class just asked the same question.

Comment: `!((c >> 5) ^ 2) & (0x07fffffeU >> (c & 31))`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35257724/testing-if-an-integer-is-an-uppercase-ascii-letter-using-bit-manipulation

Comment: @chqrlie it says that 0x07fffffeU is an illegal constant type to use in this puzzle, any way to work around that?

Comment: How about `!((c >> 5) ^ 2) & (134217726 >> (c & 31))` ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1** - Subtraction can be accomplished by adding negative numbers.

**Hint 2** - Negation can be done with bitwise operators: `-n == ~n+1`.

**Hint 3** - Right shifting a non-negative number by *n* is equivalent to dividing by 2<sup>*n*</sup>: `n>>1 == n/2`, `n>>2 == n/4`, etc.

Comment: Hint 1 isn't quite as simple as you suggest unless you can rely on a particular representation of `char` (particularly bit width, which is IIRC **at least** 8 bits). Similarly, hint 2 is assuming 2s complement. I'm probably pedanting more than the people who set the problem, though.

Comment: @Steve314: For hint 1, the C standard requires that 'subtraction' (and all other integer ops) happen on `int` sized or larger types, which are at least 16 bits (ASCII is only 7 bits).  For hint 2, the C standard requires that conversions between signed and unsigned types happen as if the machine is 2s-complement, even if it is not.

Comment: @ChrisDodd - I didn't know that, so (1) thanks, and (2) all versions of the standard? Or has this changed? However, even so, subtraction is a banned operation here so what about addition? And to subtract e.g. `1` from any positive number by adding a positive number, even if working in a wider type than `char`, you have to rely on overflow behavior - which (at least last time I checked) isn't defined by the standard for signed types. There's a workaround using bitwise and (providing you apply that before any overflow occurs), but that's still not quite as simple as John originally suggested.

Comment: @Steve314: All operations is all operations.  Overflow is well-defined for unsigned numbers.  This has been the case since C99 at least.

Comment: @Chris Dodd - Oops on "all operations", but whether `char` is signed or unsigned is *definitely* implementation-defined (and has always been signed by default for compilers I've used IIRC), so you can't just assume unsigned. Of course you could explicitly cast - assuming that's a permitted operation, though it's not listed in the question.

Comment: @Steve314: Operations between signed and unsigned values are done as unsigned, so as long as you can have constants, you can make everything unsigned, and don't have to worry about whether characters are signed or unsigned.  If you can't have constants (not mentioned in the question), things get very tough.